# how to capture the file of an input element so that I can pass it as an argument to another function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in react is there a way to capture the file of an input element so that I can pass it as an argument to a different function. I'm trying to work with the choose file popup where I will be choosing a file first and then the file needs to be sent from the upload button onClick function to make the api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {file: null};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted file:", this.state.file);
  } 
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({file: event.target.files});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>
          File:
          <input type="file" value="" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: suppose if I have a submit button below the label and is there a way to pass the file to the submit function

Comment: Thanks alot I followed the similar way 
I first stored the file in the state and retrieved it in the required function.

Comment: i'm glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to add a ref to the input field, and then you can grab the file from that point to do whatever function you want. This short article does a great job explaining the front end part of your problem. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/file-upload-with-node-js-react-js-686e342ad7e7